# DevExpress MVC HTMLEditor - In Edit Mode, It will not render model property value in HtmlEditor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress-mvc

I have created a partial view in which define HtmlEditor and bind it with Model property.
It will display content based on the dropdown value selection.
So First time when it load the Parent View and inside parent partial view, it will display value of Model Property to HtmlEditor  but when i change drop down value and render the partial view with updated value then it will not display updated content.

### AddEditHelpContent.chtml :-

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <label class="set-lable">Language</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DevExpress().ComboBoxFor(x => x.languageId, settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "Language";
                settings.Properties.TextField = "Text";
                settings.Properties.ValueField = "Value";
                settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string);
                settings.SelectedIndex = 0;
                settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "LanguageDropDownChange";
            }).BindList(Model.LstLanguage).Bind(Model.languageId).GetHtml()

        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <label class="set-lable">Content</label>
        </div>

        <div style="height:70%; width:75%;float:right;">
              @Html.Partial("_FeaturesPartial", Model)
        </div>
    </div>
```

### [JS]

```
var selectedLanguage =""
function LanguageDropDownChange(s,e)
{
    if (s != undefined)
        selectedLanguage = s.GetValue();

    htmlContent.PerformDataCallback()
}


function HtmlEditor_BeginCallback(s, e)
{
    HtmlEditor_BeginCallback
    e.customArgs['Language'] = selectedLanguage;
}

function HtmlEditor_EndCallback(s, e)
{

}

function HtmlEditor_LostFocus(s, e)
{

}
```

### _FeaturesPartial.chtml:-

```
@model OneShip.Models.HelpManagment

@using DevExpress.Utils;
@using DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor;
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc;

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.htmlContent))
{
    ViewBag.tempdata = Model.htmlContent;
}

@Html.DevExpress().HtmlEditor(
                            settings =>
                            {
                                settings.Name = "htmlContent";
                               settings.CustomDataActionRouteValues = new { Controller = "HelpManagement", Action = "FeaturesPartial"};
                                settings.Theme = "OneShipTheme";
                                settings.Html = "";
                                settings.Html = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.tempdata);
                                settings.SettingsHtmlEditing.AllowScripts = true;
                                settings.Settings.AllowHtmlView = true;
                                settings.Settings.AllowPreview = true;
                                settings.Settings.AllowDesignView = true;
                                settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "HtmlEditor_BeginCallback";
                                settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "HtmlEditor_EndCallback";
                                settings.ClientSideEvents.LostFocus = "HtmlEditor_LostFocus";
                            }).GetHtml()
```

### HelpManagementController:-

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddEditHelpContent()
        {
            HelpManagment model = new HelpManagment();
            model.LstLanguage = Common.GetAllLanguage();
            model.htmlContent = "<b>First Time Loaded Value in HTML Editor </b>";
            return View(model);
        }


    public ActionResult FeaturesPartial()
        {
            HelpManagment model = new HelpManagment();
            model.htmlContent = "<b> Based on Language selection HTML content updated in HTML Editor</b>";
            return PartialView("_FeaturesPartial",model);
        }
```

### Model :-

```
public class HelpManagment
{
       public string languageId { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LstLanguage { get; set; }
       [AllowHtml]
       public string htmlContent { get; set; }
}
```